# Open folder through excel VBA in specific size

Tags: excel, vba

Goodafternoon all,

Currently programming a small dashboard, when one of the buttons is clicked, it will go to another tab and open a folder/windows from the server. Problem is, it depends on previously opened windows how big the size of the folder will be on the screen. I would like to have this static (for example, when opening a folder through windows explorer, it should take up no more than 25% of the screen). Have looked around, but with the "activewindow" function, I reduce the size of the excel file, while I just want to reduce the size of the folder.

```
Sub OpenFolderABB()
Dim MyFolder As String
MyFolder = "\\CAG\Project OEM\ABC"
```

This part goes fine. Then I either have this line, but I can't give the exact size (except for vb"normal/minimal/maximize"Focus, which either fills the entire screen, picks up the last used size or just shows it in the taskbar)

```
Call Shell("explorer.exe" & " " & "\\CAG\Project OEM\ABC")
```

Or this line (which gives me the error that MyFolder is not an object)

```
ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink MyFolder, vbNormalFocus
    With MyFolder
        .WindowState = xlNormal
        .Height = 75
        .Width = 125
        .ScrollColumn = 1
        .ScrollRow = 1
    End With
```

And it ends with opening the other sheet. (this of course works)

```
Sheets("ABC").Activate
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

One way to open the file is with a standard DialogBox:

```
Sub OpenFolderABB()
    Dim MyFolder As String, f As String

    MyFolder = "\\CAG\Project OEM\ABC"
    ChDir MyFolder
    f = Application.GetOpenFilename()
    Workbooks.Open FileName:=f
End Sub
```

*(Note: if the `ChrDir` fails, try assigning a Mapped Drive Designator the the server)*

The DialogBox is usually full screen, but comes with Scroll Bars.  If desired you can re-size the DialogBox............... [Google](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=resize%20getopenfilename)

for details